# Java Printing to Dragon Console

Tags: java, applet

I am new to Java and I am currently making a text-based game similar to Zork. I'm planning to make it available online as an applet, but I noticed that `println` only prints to the debug console, which won't show up in the actual program.

I have added a free console emulator called [Dragon Console](http://code.google.com/p/dragonconsole/) but I have no idea how to use it. If anyone can show me how to make it display the console messages printed by `println`, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea how to use it and that's why I'm asking for help to see how to get messages from the console to show up on the terminal.

Comment: You wouldn't use `println()` in an applet. You'd output what you wanted the user to see in a UI widget. A `JTextArea` perhaps, with `setEditable(false)`

Comment: Well, you *could* use println if you created an OutputStream that was used redirected standard output to a JTextArea, but that's a lot of work for very little gain!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - I don't do Rube Goldberg machines.

Comment: I'll try a UI widget but do you know how to output messages through the Dragon Console?

Comment: Are you using a IDE like eclipse?

Comment: did you include the dragonconsole jar into your build path?

Comment: My first thought would be to actually *read* any documentation that came with "Dragon Console". But that approach might not work for you. Too mundane perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I included all components of the .jar file into the build path and imported everything. As for the documentation, I did read it but didn't understand certain parts of it.

Comment: Then perhaps a better approach here at stackoverflow would be for you to ask specific questions about what in particular in the documentation you don't understand, rather than ask for someone to re-write a whole chapter of the documentation for you, one that's already been written, with no guarantees that it would be better understood?

Comment: Voting to close this question.

Comment: Well after you implement the dragon console and run the program, all that shows up is the terminal window with nothing actually displaying on there. I don't understand what I have to do to get text to display on the console.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/dragonconsole/wiki/Implementation), it seems the DragonConsoleFrame extends JPanel which means that you can add it to a frame like any other panel.

Should be a good place to start.

Comment: Ok. Added to a JPanel frame but I still don't know how to output strings of words onto the console.

Comment: What methods have you tried calling?